# What does the C++ map() function do

Tags: arduino, accelerometer, i2c, arduino-c++

I am currently looking at the following code (which can be [found here](https://github.com/jrowberg/i2cdevlib/blob/master/Arduino/MPU6050/MPU6050.cpp))

```
void MPU6050::CalibrateAccel(uint8_t Loops,uint8_t OffsetSaveAddress) {
  double kP = 0.15;
  double kI = 8;
  float x;
  x = (100 - map(Loops, 1, 5, 20, 0)) * .01;
  kP *= x;
  kI *= x;
  PID( 0x3B,  OffsetSaveAddress,  kP, kI,  Loops);
}
```

Specifically I am struggling to understand what the line:

```
x = (100 - map(Loops, 1, 5, 20, 0)) * .01;
```

is doing?

The best matching function I can find for map() [is here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) but it doesn't appear to match the integer parameters that are being passed into the function.

Obviously ideally I would run this code but unfortunately I am yet unable to get this to compile.

Have I correctly found the function being invoked and what is the behaviour of this function with the given parameters? I assume this is a map() function similar to any other typical map function in other languages/frameworks such as python, jquery etc.

Could anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: *"unable to get this to compile"* - you should ask about this instead, Since C++ does not have standard `map` function it can do anything.

Comment: This is an arduino function. https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/math/map/

Comment: It might be some Arduino-specific thing. Start looking in its documentation?

Comment: The purpose of the `map()` function in arduino code is to expand or contract a range of values to a different range. Sometimes you want the value of a sensor to be in a different range so that you can use its value to control a servo motor or similar.

Comment: @VTT in fairness, the two problems are related. I need to understand which library is being referenced prior to being able to get the code to compile.

Comment: @drescherjm Thanks heaps for pointing me to the correct method.

Comment: This code would likely be easy to compile in the arduino ide provided it has support for your microcontroller or CPU. I am a somewhat of a beginner in the arduino world so I can't really help much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` defined in `math`, re-maps a number from one range to another. Syntax is map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)

So,  map(Loops, 1, 5, 20, 0)) means the value of variable `Loops` will be initially searched between (1,5) but result will be between 20 to 0 since it is remapped.